# GPIO LCD and Raspberry Pi 4 running FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, lcd

Does anyone know if there is a feasible way to enable a GPIO integrated LCD (built into case enclosure) in FreeBSD 13 on a Raspberry PI 4?

The case I am experimenting with follows a documentation pointing to https://github.com/goodtft and "LCD-show" which is geared towards Raspbian which I would generally prefer not to use.

Comment: First I would check if it works with PiOS and take it from there.

Comment: I don't understand how this would be pertinent to my FreeBSD issue. Pretend it does work on PiOS

Comment: Basic debugging strategy. Most drivers, setups are geared towards operation with POS. Result of that can give insight hints as to where the problem lies: LCD, Pi, OS, etc. Will not bother giving any further assistance though.